# JavaScript Image Preloading Script

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, image, ajax

I wrote an infinite scrolling scrolling plugin for an app I'm developing. When requesting the second 'page' from the server, I loop through each image, and give it a very basic `onload` function.

```
// I will have the result in a variable called data
// Fetch each image from result
$images = $( data.content ).find('img');
// Cache length for use in for loop
imagesLength = $images.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < imagesLength; i++ ) {
    // Create new Image object
    img = new Image();
    // Match src of image in the result
    img.src = ( $images[i].src );
    // Add onload listener
    img.onload = function () {
        // Increment iterator, and check if we've loaded all the images
        if( ++imageLoadingIterator == images.length) 
            _continue(); // Run _continue() if this is the case
    }
}
```

I feel like this isn't the best way to do this. Is there a way I can improve this function to run faster? For example: I'm thinking maybe creating a new `Image` object for each `img` tag is too much overhead.

Comment: Why do you think it can be sped up? Because as far as I can tell, the js can't be made much faster. If it seems slow, it's probably the actual image fetching that's taking time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really about performance, but this is more about clarity of the code.

- Attach `onload` handlers first, for readability. Appending the `src` starts the loading process. If you saw code that loaded something, expect to do something, but haven't found the handler to do it makes it a bit confusing.
- Declare one handler function in a persistent scope and have the `onload` refer to it, rather than create one handler for each onload, or creating the function everytime the whole routine executes.
- Instead of `find()`, use jQuery function's second parameter, context. With this, jQuery finds the elements with the given selector under the jQuery object that is on the second parameter.
- If the images are children of `data.content`, use `children()` instead of `find()` to avoid deep DOM traversal. Also, the lower you are in the DOM, the less deep `find()` has to dive and find your elements.
- Use strict comparison as much as possible.
- Don't forget to declare the variables and use `var`. You'd be declaring globals if you didn't.

And so:

```
var $images = $('img', data.content),
  imagesLength = $images.length,
  imageLoadingIterator = 0,
  img, i;

function onImageLoad() {
  if (++imageLoadingIterator === images.length) _continue();
}

for (i = 0; i < imagesLength; i++) {
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = onImageLoad;
  img.src = $images[i].src;
}
```

However, these advices might have a very negligible gain in performance, and might be unnecessary since the compiler might be optimizing them in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I defined the variables as you recommended already, but I forgot to paste it into the question. It was behind some other (irrelevant) code so I missed it

Comment: Also, wrap your code in a `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` to avoid problems with `jQuery.noConflict();` *and*  to keep those `var`s as local variables, instead of global. That should massivelly reduce any risk of outside manipulation and should increase the performance a bit more (since it doesn't have to access the over-crowded `window` object for your variables)